# Questions asking for a tool or offline resource

Tags: discussion

On most other Stack sites there is a close reason for searching for tools and offline resources. This reason seems to be missing on german.stackexchange.com. So would this question be on topic ? [Searching for an Android flashcard application which is integrated with some good dictionary](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/searching-for-an-android-flashcard-application-which-is-integrated-with-some-goo)